# QXmlStreamWriter, namespace and prefix

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am new to XML and trying to write the following xml using `QXmlStreamWriter` :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="url1">
        <S:Body>
                <ns2:name1 xmlns:ns2="url2">
                ..
```

So far I have tried:

```
sw.writeNamespace("url1", "S");
sw.writeStartElement("url1", "Envelope");
sw.writeStartElement("url1", "Body");

sw.writeStartElement("url2", "name1");
sw.writeNamespace("url2", "ns2");
```

but the result is not what I expect:

```
 <S:Envelope xmlns:S="url1">
            <S:Body>
                    <n1:name1 xmlns:n1="url2">
                    ..
```

As specified in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#writeNamespace), the defaut prefix `n1` is used instead of `ns2`.

If I swap the last 2 lines, I have:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="url1">
            <S:Body xmlns:ns2="url2">
                    <ns2:name1>
                    ..
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [QXmlStreamWriter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#details):

> you can bypass the stream writer's namespace support and use overloaded methods that take a qualified name instead.

That is, use this overloaded method: [QXmlStreamWriter::writeStartElement](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamwriter.html#writeStartElement-1).

I suggest you to modify your code like that:

```
sw.writeNamespace("url1", "S");

sw.writeStartElement("url1", "Envelope");
sw.writeStartElement("url1", "Body");

sw.writeStartElement("ns2:name1");
sw.writeNamespace("url2", "ns2");
```

This produces the result you have stated as desired:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="url1">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:name1 xmlns:ns2="url2">
```